# Grails: Invoking one taglib from within another

Tags: grails, taglib

I want to define my own taglib that will use the `g:datePicker` to generate some of it's output.

```
class MyTagLib

  def myTag = {attrs ->
    // I need to invoke the `datePicker` tag of the the `FormTagLib` tag library
    // provided by Grails       
  }
}
```

I want to pass along the attributes map when I invoke this tag. When I invoke `g:datePicker` I would like it to write it's output directly to the response (just as it does when you invoke it within a GSP).

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`out << g.datePicker(etc...)` ought to do it. The other taglib prefixes are metaprogrammed in automatically.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to add a body, you need to pass a closure:
`out<<g.link(action: x, {"This is a link to x"})`
or `out<<g.link(action: x) {"This is a link to x"}`